# Receiving error while running GitHub workflow

Tags: azure, terraform, github-actions

I am trying to run a simple workflow using terraform within GitHub Actions workflow using the below article, but am receiving an error.

> Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: Error retrieving keys for Storage Account "xxxxx": azure.BearerAuthorizer#WithAuthorization: Failed to refresh the Token for request to [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/\*\*\*/resourceGroups/XXXXXX/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/xxxx/listKeys?api-version=2016-01-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%5C*%5C*%5C*/resourceGroups/XXXXXX/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/xxxx/listKeys?api-version=2016-01-01): StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: adal: Refresh request failed. Status Code = '400'. Response body: {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS90002: Tenant '***' not found. This may happen if there are no active subscriptions for the tenant. Check to make sure you have the correct tenant ID. Check with your subscription administrator.\r\nTrace

Can someone guide me on what am I missing here? I am very new to this and this is my first project.

Answer (score 0):

How are you authenticating against Azure with the `azurerm` Terraform provider?

We normally use these ENV variables for GitHub Actions or Azure DevOps Pipelines:

```
export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=VALUE
export ARM_TENANT_ID=VALUE
export ARM_CLIENT_ID=VALUE
export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=VALUE
```

Comment: I have added them as github secrets at the repository settings level

Comment: I managed to resolve the error. My container name was having an extra space at the end and the uses parameter value has to be :  'uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1'  but I was using something incorrect..  But surprisingly I don't find my resource created in the azure portal even when all the steps have been completed successfully.   Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: what the the terraform plan and apply output in your GitHub Action ? Are you checking also the correct subscription in the Azure portal?